# Flatpickr not displaying current value in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr(webpacker and stimulus) in rails edit form. The birth_date has a value but flatpickr is not displaying the date. I can see in the html, the value but don't know the reason why it is not displaying the value

```
# edit.html.haml
.form-group{data: { controller: "flatpickr" } }
    = f.label :birth_date
    = f.text_field :birth_date, class: "form-control flatpickr-date"

# flatpickr_controller.js
flatpickr(".flatpickr-date", { dateFormat: "n/d/Y" });

# in browser
<input class="form-control flatpickr-date flatpickr-input" type="text" value="2020-01-09" name="user[birth_date]" id="user_birth_date" readonly="readonly">
```

Could not find any solution after googling it too.

Comment: Have you tried using `dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'` like the format of the actual value? I remember having some problems when the format is not the same as the current value. If you want to use that format I think you need to format the value to that same format.